# Why is the struct field value forgotten

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/wU44VOa_uP

Here's a simple example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Holder struct {
    i int
}

func (h Holder) SetMember(i1 int) {
    fmt.Println(i1)
    h.i = i1
}

func (h Holder) GetMember() int {
    fmt.Println(h.i)
    return h.i
}

func main() {
    c := Holder{i:3}
    c.SetMember(5)
    c.GetMember()
}
```

I'm probably missing a very basic truth about golang.
Why doesn't the value 5 stick after setting it?

This example works:
http://play.golang.org/p/j8hdKWPdsc

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Holder struct {
    i int
}

func (h *Holder) SetMember(i1 int) {
    fmt.Println(i1)
    h.i = i1
}

func (h *Holder) GetMember() int {
    fmt.Println(h.i)
    return h.i
}

func main() {
    c := &Holder{i:3}
    c.SetMember(5)
    c.GetMember()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example you passing the struct object itself, you are a pointer receiver. You see the change because you have actually modified the original object. In the first example you are passing the copy of the object that contains the same values, you are using a value receiver. You don't see the change because your original object was not changed.

To convince yourself, you can print the addresses of the objects inside `main` and your `SetMember` method.

When using pointer receiver:

In main:

```
fmt.Printf("address in main: %p\n", c)
```

In `SetMember` (should be the same as in main):

```
fmt.Printf("address in SetMember: %p\n", h)
```

When using value receiver:

In main:

```
fmt.Printf("address in main: %p\n", &c)
```

In `SetMember` (should be different from what is in main) :

```
fmt.Printf("address in SetMember: %p\n", &h)
```

Comment: oh right. So methods "defined on" a non-pointer receiver are just like global methods that get passed that receiver by value as an extra argument. (come to think of it, if the receiver is a pointer, the pointer is passed by value). Correct?

Comment: And you don't need to use a pointer receiver for your GetMember method. Using a value receiver means a caller has (some) guarantees that you will not modify the contents.

Comment: @Ovesh, I am not familiar with term `global methods`, do you means just a regular function? If so then, yes, methods defined or a struct at similar to functions where a struct is passed as an argument. This not only for non-pointer receiver.  A struct can be passed by value or it can be passed by a pointer. You could have  a function `set_member(h *Holder, new_i int)` which would change the field  `i` in the object `Holder`.